# querying objects in Morphia with mapping unknown

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I build a user interface to export documents from MongoDB.

Users will just enter the name of the db and the password, and should then be prompted for which fields they'd like to export. So I need first to be able to list these fields. This is Java based and I use Morphia.

My question is, how can I retrieve the type of objects stored in the collection, so that I can list to the user their properties? I suppose the "mapper" classes from Morphia are useful here, and surely some reflection is involved... but I don't know much about these. Any help appreciated!

Comment: How do you know which collection to query?  Or is this something the user has to define as well?

Answer (score 1):

"How you're getting the collection name" is a good question.  If you're getting the list directly from mongo, it's possible you'll end up with collections that have no backing class mapped in morphia.  You can get the mapped classes from the Mapper ((DatastoreImpl) ds).getMapper() and use that list of classes to prompt the user for which class/fields to export.

Barring that, you could always use DBCollection.findOne() to get a document from the collection, look for the classname field in the document and use that to get at the class and thus the fields available.  This doesn't preclude the possibility of the document in mongo containing unmapped data in morphia.  This can happen if you migrate your schema or you manipulate documents outside of morphia.  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score -2):

```
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo, "test_db");
    DBCollection dbc = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject query = new QueryBuilder().put("user_id").is(id).get();
    DBObject dbo = dbc.findOne(query);
    if (dbo == null) {
        log.warn("user_id is not exist.");
        return ;
    }
    Set<String> keys = dbo.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        log.info(key + " : " + dbo.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: MongoTemplate is a SpringData class, not a Morphia class, so this does not answer the question, which was how to do this using Morphia.